# Scan error: "Unbalanced parentheses" in fresh emacs installations, without config files

Tags: init-file, terminal-emacs, balanced-parentheses, emacs-mac-port, error

When I start emacs and run `M-x up-list` in the initial buffer (the about Emacs buffer, in fundamental mode) I get `Scan error: "Unbalanced parentheses"`. If I move the mark to the end of the buffer, the error gives the character range `1057, 1057` Again, this is not really a buffer of parenthesized expressions, and there certainly aren't any dangling parens at the end.

I'm on an OSX machine, running emacs 27.2 I've tried starting emacs with `-nw -Q --debug-init`. I've tried the same experiment in another buffer. If I instead go to the initial scratch buffer, both `M-x up-list` or `M-x down-list` give the same error. I presume it's not just these two commands, these are the handful I used as tests.

I don't think it should matter, but (I believe) I've also moved and renamed my `.emacs` file and my `.emacs.d` directory, so neither of these should be relevant.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling emacs via Homebrew, and tried enabling both the standard `emacs` formula and the `emacs-mac` port.

Why is the reader saying my parens are unbalanced, and how do I resolve this? What could be causing this? I can `M-x down-list` *into* a set of parens, but editing around when the reader thinks my parens are unbalanced would be very annoying.

I still don't know the actual /cause/ or /explanation/ of the problem. But the workaround solution was to uninstall, to re-reinstall, and reboot my system. It would still be nice to know how I might have resolved this without needing to reinstall or reboot my system.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on emacs 28.0.50 Linux. `up-list` returns `At top level`

Comment: Right. So something's wrong locally, as I expected. To rephrase the question, @Juancho, what could still be wrong locally on my system?